# How to pre process the key inside loop and show it as label in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I want to loop through the following json object:

```
{countryId: 1, countryName: 'Bangladesh4', countryShortName: 'BD4', authStatus: 'U', createdBy: 'nasir', …}
```

I want to show this json object as follows:

```
Country Id: 1
Country Name: Bangladesh
```

and so on. Actually I need to add a space at every capital letter of a camel case word and make the first letter capital. How can I do this in vue 3?

My try:

```
   <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(value, key) in data">
                <th>{{ key }} </th>
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code. But I would create a computed property, which creates an object with the correct labels based on the keys in the data:

```
const labels = computed(() => {
   const newLabels = {}
   data.forEach(item => {
          Object.key(key => {
             newLabels[key] = key.replace( /([A-Z])/g, " $1" );
       }) 
   })
   return newLabels;
})
```

The object created should look like this: `{countryId: 'country Id', countryName: 'country Name', ...}`. It is flexible as it will run over all objects in the data array, collecting and converting all possible keys. Downside may be performance when you have a huge array. If all keys are the same for the objects in data, you also just might create a labels object manually.

Now you can use this in your template:
 `<th style="text-transform: capitalize;">{{ labels[key] }} </th>`

I added the style to transform the first letter to a capital.

As said, I did not have an opportunity to test this, but I hope it helps you any further.

Answer (score -1):

you can display name as below

```
   <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(value, key) in data">
                <th v-if="key=='countryId'">Country Id</th>
                <th v-if="key=='countryName'">Country Name</th>
                 ...
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```